# Provision for creation of functions in Twilio autopilot from our backend

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-autopilot

I want to configure the Twilio autopilot functions to persist the user inputs and use them across the chatbot application. Is there any provision for creating functions from our backend application or are there any other provisions for getting the values in the memory so that I can use them thoroughly across my client-side chatbot application?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at Twilio Sync? You could persist some information in there, json format, and retrieve it from any other Twilio validated app or function. You can subscribe to the different item events as well, to show up-to-date information if you'd need it to change.

https://www.twilio.com/sync